# Android: How to start activity when phone is sleeping, similar to Viber incomming call activity

Tags: android

I am developing an app and this app needs to give a clear indication to the user when some event happens.

Only thing I could do until now is giving a notification in the notification area. But, I need to give a more visible notification, similar to the behavior when phone is ringing in an incoming call.

As I can understand, the reason why android is only allowing apps to give a notification is to prevent apps from disturbing the user. But, this app I am developing plays a vital role in the job of the user, so I don't think it is inappropriate to give a such strong notification.

I know it should be doable since apps like Viber can start an activity similar to a incoming phone call, even when the device is sleeping.

Does anyone know how to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding a sticky service (which does nothing) fixed the issue. Adding the service prevented the process getting killed when user exits the app and removes it from recent app list.

Because of the service, the app process is running even when a no UI is visible. In this state, if an activity is shown from the GCM service, it gets shown.

Answer (score 2):

Register a broadcast receiver, and add a custom action to it say **CustomAction**.Instead of showing notification, throw a broadcast and add **CustomAction** via intent filter.
Now in the onReceive method of broadcast listener, check
if(intent.getAction.equals("CustomAction"))`Intent i = new Intent(context, YourActivity);
context.startActivity(i);`

Sorry for not a  formatted answer, I'm driving, will update it later for more clarification.

**Update**

Register broadcast receiver in a sticky service. So that service can be started automatically if killed and register broadcast register again.
Don't forget to unregister broadcast receiver in **onDestroy()** method of service and also in **YourActivity** when you purpose is resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and this worked as expected. Can you please explain why a new activity created in the broadcast receiver gets shown but new activity created in a GCM listener service (Where I previously showed notification) is not shown when the app is not currently running?

Comment: I'm not sure about it, but there is a possibility that the application was killed. In that case while launching the activity you have to set the category Activity_Launcher in intent.

Comment: @MalwinderSingh Do you mean `intent.addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`?

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger a broascast as Vinay mentioned. If it still does not work, try using wake-locks. These wake-locks help in waking the device when it is in sleep mode. It will act like force wake and after calling wake-locks, you can perform your actions.

Hope it helped..

Thanks.